Error in code _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button4"
After 2-nd press of buttons paper/scissors/rock gives an error:
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button4"

How can I fix it?
Here's the code:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from random import randint

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x512')
root.resizable(0, 0)
player_selection = ''
psr = ['p', 's', 'r']
ai_selection = ''
game_result = ''
index = 0
ai_image, player_image = '', ''
imgpaper = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='paper.png')
imgscissors = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='scissors.png')
imgrock = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='rock.png')
imgempty = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='empty.png')

def ai_moves():
    global ai_selection, index
    index = randint(0, 2)
    ai_selection = psr[index]
    image_to_output_ai()
    win_check()

def image_to_output_ai():
    global ai_image, ai_selection
    if ai_selection == 'p':
        ai_image = imgpaper
    elif ai_selection == 's':
        ai_image = imgscissors
    elif ai_selection == 'r':
        ai_image = imgrock
    elif ai_selection == '':
        ai_selection = imgempty

def image_to_output_player():
    global player_image
    if player_selection == 'p':
        player_image = imgpaper
    elif player_selection == 's':
        player_image = imgscissors
    elif player_selection == 'r':
        player_image = imgrock
    elif player_selection == '':
        player_image = imgempty

def block_buttons():
    btnpaper.config(state='disabled')
    btnscissors.config(state='disabled')
    btnrock.config(state='disabled')

def win_check():
    global game_result, ai_selection
    global ai_image
    image_to_output_player()
    player_label.config(image=player_image)
    ai_label.config(image=ai_image)
    if player_selection == ai_selection:
        game_result = 'draw'
    elif (player_selection == 'p' and ai_selection == 'r') or (player_selection == 's' and ai_selection == 'p') or (player_selection == 'r' and ai_selection == 's'):
        game_result = 'win'
    elif (ai_selection == 'p' and player_selection == 'r') or (ai_selection == 's' and player_selection == 'p') or (ai_selection == 'r' and player_selection == 's'):
        game_result = 'lose'
    block_buttons()
    restart_btn.place(x=350, y=320)
    print(game_result)

def player_selection_def(what):
    global player_selection
    player_selection = what
    ai_moves()

def restart():
    player_label.config(image=imgempty)
    ai_label.config(image=imgempty)
    btnpaper.config(state='normal')
    btnscissors.config(state='normal')
    btnrock.config(state='normal')
    ai_selection, player_selection = '', ''
    ai_image, player_image = '', ''
    if 'restart_btn' in globals():
        restart_btn.destroy()

btnpaper = tk.Button(root, text='paper', font='arial 18 bold', command=lambda: player_selection_def('p'))
btnpaper.place(width=135, height=54, x=50, y=400)
btnscissors = tk.Button(root, text='scissors', font='arial 18 bold', command=lambda: player_selection_def('s'))
btnscissors.place(width=135, height=54, x=280, y=400)
btnrock = tk.Button(root, text='rock', font='arial 18 bold', command=lambda: player_selection_def('r'))
btnrock.place(width=135, height=54, x=525, y=400)
player_label = tk.Label(root)
player_label.place(x=50, y=50)
ai_label = tk.Label(root)
ai_label.place(x=400, y=50)
label_win_lose = tk.Label(text='', font='arial 18 bold')
label_win_lose.place(x=350, y=300)
restart_btn = tk.Button(text='try again', font='arial 18 bold', command=restart)
root.mainloop()

after EACH paper/scissors/rock button press, what happens after the first paper/scissors/rock button press should happen. but after 2-nd press of buttons paper/scissors/rock gives an error:
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button4"

Errors like this almost always happen due to trying to reuse a tkinter object after you've destroyed it. E.g. destroying the restart button in the restart() function.

I'm not sure what if 'restart_btn' in globals(): was supposed to accomplish - that condition will always be true, calling .destroy() on the widget doesn't cause the variable referring to it to change in any way.


error in code _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button4"

The problem can be fixed.
Comment out line 66 and move this restart_btn.place(x=350, y=320) after line 97.
restart_btn = tk.Button(text='try again', font='arial 18 bold', command=restart)
restart_btn.place(x=350, y=520) #<== change value 320 to 520

Comment out line 82 and 82
#if restart_btn in globals():
    #restart_btn.destroy()

You ready to go.
Edit:
Screenshot:


thx, helped me! nice images btw

Glad I could help. Btw, I don't images for paper, scissors and rock
